# Function that takes an object with optional/default properties as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, default-value

I understand that, using ES6 syntax, a function can be made that takes an object as a parameter and that parameter can have a default value, like so:

```
function exampleFunction(objParam = {val1: 1, val2: 2}) {
    //...
}
```

If I call `exampleFunction()`,`objParam` is given the default value. However, if I call `exampleFunction({val1: 3})`, `objParam.val2` is `undefined`. This makes sense, because the default isn't being applied. Is there any way I can make sure that `objParam.val2` does have a value, using the ES6 notation? I know I can add checks within the function, but that introduces inconsistency in the code and I'd rather not.

Edit: To clarify, here is a better example:

```
function exampleFunction(param = 0, objParam = {val1: 1, val2: 2}) {
    return objParam.val1;
}
exampleFunction(); // Returns 1 (this is good)
exampleFunction(1, {val1: 2}); // Returns 2 (this is good)
exampleFunction(1, {val2: 3}); // Returns undefined (I want it to return 1)
```

And here's what I currently have, which does work but is somewhat inelegant:

```
function exampleFunction(param = 0, objParam = {val1: 1, val2: 2}) {
    if(objParam.val1 === undefined) objParam.val1 = 1
    if(objParam.val2 === undefined) objParam.val2 = 2
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, that's not really possible. The default value for a parameter is just that - a default value. It doesn't handle merging properties of objects that are passed in. You should do that yourself using `Object.assign`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in parameters to provide default values:

```js
function exampleFunction({val1 = 1, val2 = 2} = {}) {
  console.log(val1, val2);
}
exampleFunction({val1: 5});
exampleFunction();
```

If you want to keep the parameter as an object, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
function exampleFunction(origParams = {}) {
  const objParam = Object.assign({ val1: 1, val2: 2 }, origParams);
  console.log(objParam.val1, objParam.val2);
}
exampleFunction({val1: 5});
exampleFunction();
```

Comment: +1 to @ElAoutarHamza's question, and I'd also like to see a way to keep the parameter as an object if possible. For example, instead of accessing it as `val1`, access it as `param.val1`.

Comment: @Ian After my edit it handles undefined values too. If you want to keep the parameter as an object, you have to use `Object.assign` or object spread syntax, like in Sam's answer.

Comment: This article https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6 goes into a but more detail.

Answer (score 10):

Probably not as clean as you're looking for, but you can do this instead

```
function exampleFunction(objParams) {
  const defParams = { val1: 1, val2: 2 };

  const finalParams = { ...defParams, ...objParams }
  // final params takes the default params and overwrites any common properties with incoming params

  // ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me and it is cleaner than the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `Object.assign`, no need to define separate variables.

**You can reassign the parameter itself**. First, provide the default values, then the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) of the parameter. This will use the default values if not provided via the parameter, and it will keep additional properties that are part of the parameter but not given as a default.

```js
function demo(sizes) {
  sizes = {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    ...sizes // this is where the magic (called object destructuring) happens
  }
  console.log(sizes)
}

demo({width: 400, depth: 20})  // Prints "Object { width: 400, height: 100, depth: 20 }"
```

Alternatively, you can put the defaults in a separate object:

```js
const DEFAULT_SIZES = {
    width: 200,
    height: 100
}

function demo(sizes) {
  sizes = {
    ...DEFAULT_SIZES
    ...sizes
  }
  console.log(sizes)
}

demo({width: 400, depth: 20})  // Prints "Object { width: 400, height: 100, depth: 20 }"
```